# db2 stored procedure returning ref cursor

Tags: sql, db2

I am new to db2 stored procedures and have a question about creating a procedure that returns a reference cursor (to be read by a java program).

I am using db2 control center to try and compile the procedure in...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EPOS.REP_MAN_DAILY_TRAN_COUNTS()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
READS SQL DATA
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE c CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
select 'x' from sysibm.sysdummy1
union 
select 'p' from sysibm.sysdummy1;
OPEN c;
END
```

I get an error saying ...

OPEN c
DB21028E  The cursor "C" has not been declared.

But I have declared C... so I am a bit confused. Does this procedure look right? Maybe i can't compile using db2 control center?

thanks

Comment: Stored procedure are compiled directly in the database. Do not longer use the Control Center, instead start to use DataStudio. Have you runned from the DB2CLP? db2 -td@ -f myStoredP.sql

Comment: thanks. That worked!!! db2 -td@ -svf sp.sql

Comment: I wrote the same in the answers part. Just yo close the question

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, this procedure does not return a _ref cursor_; it returns a result set, which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not specify the character separator. If you are using the db2 clp, make sure the procedure finishes by a @ and then call it like this for a file called procedure.sql

```
db2 -td@ -f procedure.sql
```